# nginx locations not loaded correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, nginx-location

I have a server where I have an Angular app and a nodejs backend.

The backend runs on port 4000

I use nginx as reverse proxy and here is my config

```
 server{
  server_name _;
  location / {
    root /var/www/haymrFront;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /tgup-api/ {
    proxy_pass "http://localhost:4000/";
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when I send a request to my server/tgup_api/, the angular app gets it. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with app gets it? Did you try to call it from an external client?

Comment: What I mean is /tgup-api falls on the Angular app instead of paxying to the backend server. When I curl my ip:4000 I reach the backend and when I curl my ip/tgup-api/ I fall on the Angular app

Answer (score 0):

you don't need quotes for proxy_pass

just use

```
location /tgup-api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
```